# How to convert BitmapImage into StorageFile?

Tags: bitmap, drag-and-drop, storage, clipboard, uwp-xaml

While drag and drop of an image I need to convert BitmapImage into StorageFile to upload it.

```
       DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
       if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
       {
                    RandomAccessStreamReference img = await dataPackageView.GetBitmapAsync();
                    var imgstream = await img.OpenReadAsync();
                    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmap.SetSource(imgstream);
                    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(bitmap.UriSource.ToString()));

                    IUploadFileModel   _uploadModel = ObjFactory.Instance.CreateUploadFileModel();
                  _uploadModel.UploadFileAsync(file, user, OpenChatData.TeamID.ToString(), _isReadReceiptEnabled);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert the data obtained from the clipboard to `BitmapImage`, you can directly operate the `RandomAccessStreamReference` obtained, save it to a local file, and upload the file

```cs
var data = Clipboard.GetContent();
if (data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
{
    var img = await data.GetBitmapAsync();
    var imgstream = await img.OpenReadAsync();
    string type = imgstream.ContentType;
    string extension = type.Replace("image/", "");
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync($"temp.{extension}", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[imgstream.Size];
    await imgstream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)imgstream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, buffer);
    // upload file
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This method increases the actual size of the image. For example, I have uploaded file size as 287 kb but when I fetch the same image It becomes 877 kb

Comment: Hello, I did not reproduce your problem. In this method (`byte[] buffer = new byte[imgstream.Size]`), the size of the generated file is the same as the `Bitmap` in the clipboard. Did you re-encode the image during the upload process?